# ffmpeg: Merge short audio sound between two audio streams

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have two videos `input1.mp4` and `input2.mp4` both of them with duration of 60 seconds. I also have one 8 seconds long audio input `sound.mp3`. So right now I'm concatenating these two videos with `xfade` transition and I' trying to place the `sound.mp3` right between these two videos.

[image]

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i sound.mp3 -filter_complex "xfade=transition=radial:duration=0.3:offset=60;[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.3000" output.mp4
```

How can I achieve such effect. I've tried splitting the `sound.mp3` in two parts and appending them at the end and beginning of the videos. Also tried adding negative offset with `itsoffset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mix in the sound with the result of the acrossfade output, after delaying the sound start.

`ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i sound.mp3 -filter_complex "xfade=transition=radial:duration=0.3:offset=60;[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.3000[a];[2]adelay=56s:all=1[s];[a][s]amix=inputs=2:dropout_transition=0:normalize=0" output.mp4`

Use latest ffmpeg.